# pandas subtract on multiindex level matching

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, subtraction

I have a pandas dataframe with two multiindex levels

```
df
Out[202]: 
                     A         B         C         D
first second                                        
1     1      -0.080810  0.865259 -0.371148  0.346480
      2      -0.026636  1.259460 -1.109295 -0.871204
      3       0.372008 -1.778272  0.727838  0.620727
      4       0.918075  0.564741  2.027432 -1.614162
      5      -0.373527 -0.186027  0.225399  0.722733
2     1       0.344241  0.170596 -0.050763  2.692102
      2      -1.665413  0.357033 -0.691327 -0.983103
      3       1.277470 -1.841702  0.582107 -0.454315
      4       2.374108 -0.557879  0.797296  0.803622
      5      -1.001092  0.131217  0.131378 -0.636299
```

I also have a second dataframe consisting of two rows out of the original dataframe, corresponding to the multiindex level 'second == 1'

```
to_subtract = df.query('second == 1')  
to_subtract
Out[200]: 
                     A         B         C         D
first second                                        
1     1      -0.080810  0.865259 -0.371148  0.346480
2     1       0.344241  0.170596 -0.050763  2.692102
```

I want to subtract 'df' by 'to_subtract' on the first level, but for all values that correspond to the first level of the multiindex. Pandas knows how to subtract based on matching ALL levels of the multiindex, as shown below

```
df.sub(to_subtract)
Out[201]: 
                A    B    C    D
first second                    
1     1       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
      2       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      3       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      4       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      5       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     1       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
      2       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      3       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      4       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      5       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Question is, how do I subtract all values from df[first===1] by to_subtract[first==1], and all values from df[first==2] by to_subtract[first==2]. I assume I can do a for loop and loop through everything, but I would rather avoid that if I can, since these dataframes may get large in the future.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need remove second level of `MultiIndex` and then add parameter `level=0` for align by first levels in [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
to_subtract = df.query('second == 1').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
#same as
#to_subtract = df.xs(1, level=1)
print (to_subtract)
              A         B         C         D
first                                        
1     -0.080810  0.865259 -0.371148  0.346480
2      0.344241  0.170596 -0.050763  2.692102

df1 = df.sub(to_subtract, level=0)
print (df1)
                     A         B         C         D
first second                                        
1     1       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
      2       0.054174  0.394201 -0.738147 -1.217684
      3       0.452818 -2.643531  1.098986  0.274247
      4       0.998885 -0.300518  2.398580 -1.960642
      5      -0.292717 -1.051286  0.596547  0.376253
2     1       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
      2      -2.009654  0.186437 -0.640564 -3.675205
      3       0.933229 -2.012298  0.632870 -3.146417
      4       2.029867 -0.728475  0.848059 -1.888480
      5      -1.345333 -0.039379  0.182141 -3.328401
```

Comment: Yep! that works, thanks for the help. As a side note, I notice that by doing this 'to_subtract' loses one of its multiindex levels. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without that happening to 'to_subtract'?

Comment: @MattP. - In my opinion not, need remove it.

Comment: As of pandas version 1.4.2, `df - to_subtract` or `df.sub(to_subtract)` work just fine - no need for `level=0` any more. As far as I can tell this is because pandas matches on as many shared index levels as possible. I'm not sure if this was formerly not the case; maybe `level=0` was never required. The real magic, as far as I can see, is `df.xs()`, which is a super-elegant way to select by a MultiIndex level *and* drop that level, which works perfectly for this use case.